# Why after inserting in index.html file font awesome fonts a square appears in Angular 7 project?

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I have inserted CDN in index.html file of my project of Angular 7 framework. Then I have inserted icon html tag in my component html file. But instead of icon a square appears. I have tried with different font awesome versions, but there always this square instead of icon appears. Maybe you have something to advice?

#### Index.html CDN script

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

#### Icon in HTML

```
<i class="fab fa-accessible-icon"></i>
```

Comment: Can you provide the CDN you've added in your index.html and show an example of the icon markup you've tried to use in your html?

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon"></i>

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: No, this is not a problem. Nothing have changed.

Comment: I have found the solution. The problem was that I was using one font of google fonts and they were not supporting these icons. I have tried with default fonts and the icon appeared.